# How to convert int32Array to java int []?

Tags: java, itk

I have:

```
int32Array hh = int32Array.frompointer(img.getBufferAsInt32());
```

This resulted from taking a pointer to the simpleitk image data. Can anyone help me in converting this array type into a regular java array?

**EDIT**

I tried another approach where i inherited from itkImage class and got the Cptr pointer to the image buffer as long
I also found a memory pointer class  in Java where i can get my array from

```
        com.sun.jna.Pointer ptr = new com.sun.jna.Memory(2 * 512 * 512);
       // ptr.share(_pointer);
        int testarr[] = new int[512 * 512];
        ptr.read(_pointer, testarr, 0, testarr.length);
```

The problem now is how to copy the Cptr pointer to the Java pointer (equal operator does not work)

Comment: The obvious thing would be to loop and convert each element, but this is probably very slow.

Comment: Yes @AleksG that's why i took the pixel data as a pointer and didnt use GetPixelValue because i have to loop over the image

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array of the same size as the previous and type int, copy all the data
from the old to the new one while casting it to an int with (int).

```
 int[] newArray = new int[hh.length];

    for(int i=0; i<hh.length; i++){
        array[i] = (int)hh[i];
    }
```

Comment: And this differs from my comment how?  And also note the response comment form the OP.  Your answer doesn't exactly help.

Comment: I tried another approach but i got trapped there too :) i edited the anwer..thanks guys for your concern

Comment: By doing the read operation you do copy it right?

read(long offset, byte[] buf, int index, int length)
Indirect the native pointer, copying from memory pointed to by native pointer, into the specified array.

What kind of error does it give you?